# jQuery:form can not be submitted after using `jquery-validation`'s remote validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am using "jquery-validation" https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation to validate my form,

there is a question,that is:

form can not be submitted after using jquery-validation's remote validation.If remote method deleted,it's ok.

what should I do?thanks in advance.

**view:**

```
<form id="register" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong></span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
            @if ($errors->has('email'))
               <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong></span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong></span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation">
            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong></span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Register
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**javascript:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $("#register").validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    rangelength: [4, 30],
                    remote: {
                        url: "{{url('services/validation/verify_name')}}",
                        type: "post"
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    minlength: 9,
                    maxlength: 30,
                    remote: {
                        url: "{{url('services/validation/verify_email')}}",
                        type: "post"
                    }
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    rangelength: [6, 20]
                },
                "password_confirmation": {
                    equalTo: "#password"
                }
            },
            errorClass: "has-danger",

            success: function (label, elem) {
                var element = $(elem);
                if (element.is('input[name="name"]')) {
                    label.html("available");
                } else if (element.is('input[name="email"]')) {
                    label.html("available");
                }
            },

            highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                $(element).fadeOut(function () {
                    $(element).fadeIn();
                });
                $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass(errorClass);
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass(errorClass);
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what is returned by server for remote request? Can inspect using browser dev tools in network tab

Comment: thanks,I should change the url like `url: "{{url('services/validation/verify_name')}}"` to `url: "services/validation/verify_name"`

Answer (score 0):

I should modify the urls:

```
url: "{{url('services/validation/verify_name')}}",
url: "{{url('services/validation/verify_email')}}",
```

they should be:

```
url: "services/validation/verify_name",
url: "services/validation/verify_email",
```